# Temperature increase during friction

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

There is pin made of Asbestos and two disc material Aluminum and steel in first experiment i used Aluminum disc with asbestos pin in wear test the disc is rotating and the asbestos was in frictional contact with Aluminum after 3 minutes i measured the temperature of Aluminum  disc and asbestos pin by infrared thermometer  i found that the Aluminum disc temperature is higher than the pin...and when i replace the disc material to Steel and repeat the experiment i found that the Steel disc temperature is lower than the pin temperature...and when i compared the two cases i found that Aluminum disc temperature is higher than Steel disc and when i compared the temperature  of the pin in both cases i found that the pin temperature when contact with steel is higher than when contact with aluminum..i didn't understand that behavior...what the reason of that?

Comment: Related question: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/203401/26969

Comment: It might be helpful to state the pin material - thermal conductivity is an important factor. Also it matters exactly where / how you measure the pin temperature (and what the heat sinking arrangement is).

Comment: The pin material is Asbestos and i measure the temperature of pin and disc by Infrared thermometer exactly in the friction point.

Comment: ...pin temeperature? Of what pin? I think there is some context missing here.

Comment: I edit the question please can you check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thermal conductivity of steel is significantly less than that of aluminum.  Heat generated by the friction of asbestos on the surfaces of both discs is carried away much faster by aluminum than by steel.  Therefore the steel disc in the viscinity of contact with the pin, as well as the asbestos pin, will retain heat and will measure a higher temperature than the aluminum disc.

The [thermal conductivity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/tables/thrcn.html) of steel is 50.2 W/m K, and of aluminum is 205.0 W/m K.  [Thermal conductivity](http://www.ccfltd.co.uk/Trade-Support/Calculating_U_Values) is expressed as Watts per square meter of surface area per degree kelvin, through one meter of thickness.